# test daily cron job in node js

Tags: node.js, cron

I have a cron job that should run every day at 8:00,
I want to do testing on it, and I need when I check the current date it should give me the fake date. is there a way I can auto fake the time every few minutes to the next day?
and I need to select from a database if a timestamp matches the current date

```
import { CronJob } from "cron"

let job = new CronJob('0 0 7 * * *',()=>{
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())
    knex('users').select('*').where('date_stamp', new Date())
})

job.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `runOnInit` (7th argument - see the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#api)) value to `true`. This way it will run the job right when it's created.

```
let job = new CronJob('* * 7 * * *',()=>{
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())
}, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, true);
```

Or you can set the interval based on your environment.

```
const isDev = process.env.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev';
const cronTime = isDev
    ? '0 * * * * *' // dev interval - every minute
    : '* * 7 * * *'; // prod interval

let job = new CronJob(cronTime,()=>{
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())
});
```

Comment: i need to have the current date to select from a database, i have updated the question.